# Matlab compiler indicator flag

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

Hi I use Matlab code that sometimes is compiled.
Can I check that inside the code?
for example

if compiled_with_mcr
   then
end

Comment: http://img.pandawhale.com/post-37094-Tom-Cruise-WHAT-gif-Oblivion-I-wDog.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `isdeployed`. This returns `true` when called within an application compiled with MATLAB Compiler, and `false` when called from within live MATLAB.